# How to call a function using an argument supplied from the template function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

EDIT: Just to clarify "t" is successfully called when casted. The compiler knows and does state that it is a function pointer that takes an argument of type int. I supply a null int pointer to break the loop because it is calling itself recursively. It may just be a bug in the compiler.

I am trying to call a function from a template function argument.
 I would assume that it would be possible to call the function without explicit casting but that does not seem to be the case. Using VC2013.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T t)
{

    printf("calling func...\n");

    if (t)
    {
        ((void(__cdecl*)(int))t)((int)nullptr);     // explicit casting is successful

        t ((int)nullptr);                           // compile error: ``term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments``

    }

}

void main()
{

    auto pe = func < int > ;
    auto pf = func < void(__cdecl*)(int) >;

    pf(pe);


}
```

Comment: One suggestion concerning casts: Casting a `nullptr` to `int` is obviously rubbish. Guessing what you want to achieve though, I would guess that you want a default-initialized `T`. E.g. if `T` is some pointer type, you want a null pointer, if it's an `int` you want a zero. The way to achieve that is simply `T()`, like `T nil = T();`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the error for `func<int>` which becomes:

```
void func(int t)
{
    printf("calling func...\n");

    if (t)
    {
        ((void(__cdecl*)(int))t)((int)nullptr); // bad casting
        t ((int)nullptr);                       // compile error: int is not a callable object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `t` is an `int`, of course you can't treat it like a function. You'll have to specialize the template for `int`s or use a different function. Also, please forget that there are C-style casts, they only serve to shoot yourself into the foot.

Comment: t is not int, t is of type: void (__cdecl*)(int) at the point of failure.

Comment: Actually, I just threw the code at GCC (after fixing some obvious bugs) and you can remove the second and third line of `main()` and it still doesn't compile. I hereby claim that it is as people have suggested here, that you are trying to call an `int` as a function. Note that your "works with a cast" is no indication that this isn't the case, as the code never actually gets executed, but at compile time the call that is never made must still be valid.

Comment: Ok you just verified that template implementation is broken in GCC as well. The code gets executed trust me. The buggy line *should* be valid code but these compilers are poorly crafted unfortunately.

Comment: `func<int>` is called with a zero as argument, so the code within `if(t)` is *NOT* executed, trust me. However, that code still has to be valid and it isn't, as two compilers and several C++ programmers pointed out to you. You're welcome. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want exactly. But maybe something like this ?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void call_helper(T value, std::true_type) // value is function
{
    std::cout << "Function" << std::endl;
    value(0);
}

template<typename T>
void call_helper(T value, std::false_type) // value is NOT function
{
    std::cout << "Not function" << std::endl;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void call(T value)
{
    call_helper(value, std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>());
}

int main()
{
    void (*f)(int) = call<int>;
    call(f);
}
```

live example: http://rextester.com/DIYYZ43213